# Set property in Java bean class

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have created  a from which have a text field name 'empId' whose value is set into a bean class through a jsp page using `<jsp:setProperty>` tag

**note:empId is of int type in bean class**

when i write the following code

```
<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="empId" value="empId"/>
```

It will work fine
but when i write the following code

```
<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="empId" value="<%=request.getParameter("empId")%>"/>
```

then it is not working
gives the exception JasperException

Comment: i think String to primitive type conversion is not works?but question is that how it works in first case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EL` expression.

use `${param.empId}` if you want to map request parameter.

`<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="empId" value="${param.empId}`"/>

PS: @Sheo you have to show exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
String employeeID = (String) request.getParameter("employeeID");

<jsp:setProperty value="<%=employeeID%>" ..../>
```

Hope it works :)

........../