# How to Get and Set values using beans in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp and beans. How shall I set and Get the value of bean in jsp?
I am made a project in jsp. how will i get that value from jsp to bean

Comment: Refer link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html

Comment: similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666182/set-property-in-java-bean-class?rq=1